# INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR while creating payment in PayPal SandBox, MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, paypal

I have ran out of ideas and none of the answers for the similar question was helpful, hence I am desperate now. I am trying to integrate paypal payment into my app. I have set negative testing to off in my sandbox account. I am using visual studio 2013, here is my example code:

```
Address billingAddress = new Address();
billingAddress.line1 = "52 N Main ST";
billingAddress.city = "Johnstown";
billingAddress.country_code = "US";
billingAddress.postal_code = "43210";
billingAddress.state = "OH";

CreditCard creditCard = new CreditCard();
creditCard.number = "4417119669820331";
creditCard.type = "visa";
creditCard.expire_month = 11;
creditCard.expire_year = 2018;
creditCard.cvv2 = "874";
creditCard.first_name = "Joe";
creditCard.last_name = "Shopper";
creditCard.billing_address = billingAddress;

var amountDetails = new Details();
amountDetails.subtotal = "7.41";
amountDetails.tax = "0.03";
amountDetails.shipping = "0.03";

Amount amount = new Amount();
amount.total = "7.47";
amount.currency = "USD"; 
amount.details = amountDetails;

Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
transaction.amount = amount;
transaction.description = "This is the payment transaction description.";

List<Transaction> transactions = new List<Transaction>();
transactions.Add(transaction);

FundingInstrument fundingInstrument = new FundingInstrument();
fundingInstrument.credit_card = creditCard;

List<FundingInstrument> fundingInstruments = new List<FundingInstrument>();
fundingInstruments.Add(fundingInstrument);

Payer payer = new Payer();
payer.funding_instruments = fundingInstruments;
payer.payment_method = "credit_card";

Payment payment = new Payment();
payment.intent = "sale";
payment.payer  = payer;
payment.transactions = transactions;

var config = ConfigManager.Instance.GetProperties();
var accessToken = new OAuthTokenCredential(config).GetAccessToken();

        try
        {
            var apiContext = new APIContext(accessToken);
            var createdPayment = payment.Create(apiContext);
        }
        catch (PayPal.HttpException e)
        {
            return Json(e.InnerException, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Now each time I am attempting to create the payment, I am getting the following:

```
"{\"name\":\"INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR\",\"message\":\"An internal service error has occurred\",\"information_link\":\"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR\",\"debug_id\":\"f0d2f70ac4693\"}"
```

debug_id changes each time i attempt. any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the credit card number you're using to a different number.  This error has been happening a lot in the recent weeks on PayPal's sandbox environment and is (most of the time) related to overusing a credit card number.  The best thing to try would be to create a new Sandbox test account via the Developer Dashboard and generate a new credit card number there.

The PayPal payments team is currently working on a solution on sandbox to return a more meaningful error when this happens.

**EDIT:**

As an alternative to creating a new Sandbox test account to get a new credit card number for testing, you can also try the credit card number generator available in the following FAQ on the PayPal Technical Support site:

> [Sandbox - Generate an Additional Credit Card Number for a Sandbox account](https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/750).

Scroll down to **Step 4** on that page to find the generator.